# Does NLog block logging when a previous log is compressed?

Tags: nlog

Our application uses NLog for logging.
Logging is performed synchronously. A new log file is created every day. Log compression is enabled. Log configuration is done programmatically:

```
logfile = new FileTarget("debuglogfile")
            {
                FileName = Path.Combine(logDirectory, "debug.log"),
                KeepFileOpen = true,
                ConcurrentWrites = true,
                EnableArchiveFileCompression = true,
                ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
                MaxArchiveFiles = 10,
                ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date,
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8                
            };
config.AddRuleForAllLevels(logfile);
```

Typically, our application performs about 50 log entries every second. The size of the log for a day is about 2 GB. Obviously, compression of such a log takes quite a long time.
At the beginning of the day, when the compression of the log for the previous day is performed, we see a gap of one or two minutes between the log entries. At the same time, the application does not perform its functions. It looks like the application threads are blocked when writing to the log.
But if we disable compression, the program works normally.

**Details:**
NLog version: 5.2.7
Target framework: net7.0
Operating system: Ubuntu

1. Please clarify whether logging is blocked while the previous log is being compressed.
2. If yes, what should be done to make the program able to write to a new log in parallel with the compression of the previous log.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when enabling `EnableArchiveFileCompression = true` then the [NLog FileTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target) will for every LogEvent check if archive operation is needed and perform the file-compression as part of the archive-operation. After the archive-operation has completed, then it will write the LogEvent to the new file.

If the file-compression takes a long time, then it will delay the writing of LogEvent. If Nlog FileTarget is called synchronous without [NLog AsyncWrapper](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target), then the application-thread will be blocked until the file-compression has completed.

Maybe consider setting up a scheduled task / cron-job to perform file-compression instead of depending on the NLog FileTarget. Alternative perform the archive roll every hour to reduce the file-size. Or if on Window then consider using NTFS compression for the archive folder.